# zuul eureka service id redirection

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am having few spring boot microservices, which are deployed to JBoss over a cloud environment. These boot services are Eureka clients which register itself in to the Eureka server. Following is an example:

```
eureka:
  client:
    healthcheck:
        enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: ${DISCOVERY_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/


  instance:
    ip-address: 127.0.0.1
    appname: user-regn-service-app
    home-page-url-path: /user-regn-service-app
```

It registers the app with Eureka with the name user-regn-service-app
[Eureka Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUTER.png)

The wildfly server is running at 8080 and the user-regn-service-app is deployed at the context path /user-regn-service-app.
So the rest api is as below

```
localhost:8080/user-regn-service-app/regnUser
```

When I am using zuul as api gateway, the config is as below

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    test:
      path: /test/**
      service-id: USER-REGN-SERVICE-APP
      strip-prefix: true


ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: false
```

But whenever I am making call to zuul api gateway it is unable to recognize the context path and redirects to localhost:8080 instead of localhost:8080/user-regn-service-app.

`http://localhost:8765/api/` -> 404 not found

`http://localhost:8765/api/user-regn-service-app/` -> Wildfly default homepage

`http://localhost:8765/api/user-regn-service-app/user-regn-service-app/regnUser` -> Redirects to user registration.

Expected behavior: `http://localhost:8765/api/test/regnUser` should redirect to the user registration.

I have pretty much tried all combinations that I got from blogs between Zuul and Eureka to get the following done but no luck. Kindly advise if I am missing something.

I have tried using custom zuul custom filter as below but it doesn't forward to the Required Context path. Code is as below

```
@Component
public class ZuulApiFilter extends ZuulFilter{

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        System.out.println("original"+ ctx.get("requestURI"));
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        String contextAwareURI=requestURI.concat("user-regn-service-app/");
        ctx.set("requestURI", contextAwareURI);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

}
```

The requestURI doesn't changes after setting the new URI as well
ctx.set("requestURI", contextAwareURI);
request.getRequestURI(); shows the old Request URI only.

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove `ZuulApiFilter` and try setting:

`strip-prefix: false`

and try sending the request to:

`http://<zuul ip>:<zuul port>/api/test/....`

Edited:

@Tanmay Ghosh

Here is a sample code I'm using for Zuul-related blog post (still in draft) that I'll publish in the next couple of days:

`Zuul`'s `application.yml`:

```
...
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8000/eureka/

# ribbon.eureka.enabled: false
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    zuulDemo1:
      path: /zuul1/**
# serviceId as registed with Eureka. Enabled and used when ribbon.eureka.enabled is true.
      serviceId: demo-zuul-api1
# zuul.routes.<the route>.url used when ribbon.eureka.enabled is false, serviceId is disabled.
#      url: http://localhost:8600/
# stripPrefix set to true if context path is set to /
      stripPrefix: true
...
```

And actually my Zuul server repo is public and available at: https://bitbucket.org/asimio/zuulserver and a recent blog post at http://tech.asimio.net/2017/10/10/Routing-requests-and-dynamically-refreshing-routes-using-Spring-Cloud-Zuul-Server.html

Another thing, Does the Zuul service also uses an app context other than / ? If so, Could you try sending the request via Zuul at: `http://<zuul host>:<zuul port>/<zuul app context>/api/test/....` ?

Comment: If i make it false i can access the below
http://localhost:8765/api/user-regn-service-app/ -> Wildfly homepage

http://localhost:8765/api/user-regn-service-app/user-regn-service-app/userRegn ->Service

Not sure if any config is missing

Comment: This is confusing, are you using JBoss and Weblogic?
If the API is listening at `localhost:8080` and also using app context `user-regn-service-app` it means requests should be sent to `http://localhost:8080/user-regn-service-app/<the resource>`. 
stripPrefix is set to true if context path of the API (not Zuul service) is set to /

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,I am using Jboss Wildfly for this service and it is deployed at the context root /user-regn-service-app at 8080.
http://localhost:8080/user-regn-service-app/<the resource> works fine, but zuul is unable to redirect to the given service. Am I missing something in the config?

Comment: Setting `strip-prefix: true` causes `Zuul` to proxy the request to the API service without the app context, meaning `Zuul` is most-likely sending the request to `http://localhost:8080/<the resource>`

Comment: I have updated my answer with some sample code I'm using for a Zuul-related blog post I'll be publishing either today or tomorrow

Comment: Thank for your response.. i will try it to see if it works well for me. My Zuul server is working at root context only at port 8765 which is using service id from Eureka server running at 8761.